# Function in other function is not accessible

Tags: javascript

I declare two functions:

```
var vec = function(x,y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
};
var ray = function(start,end){
    this.origin = start;
    this.direction = end;
};
```

In the `canvas.onmousemove` event I would like to use these functions as objects:

```
canvas.onmousemove = function(event){
  var ray = new ray(new vec(center_x,center_y), new vec(2,10));
};
```

But my browser is telling me that the functions are undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because the **variable name** (`ray`) is the same as the **function name** (`ray`)

Change  `ray` variable name on this line

```
 var ray = new ray(new vec(center_x,center_y), new vec(2,10));
```

Into a different name, like `rayInstance`. A **meaningful name** will help you on the future.

```
var rayInstance = new ray(new vec(center_x, center_y), new vec(2, 10));
```

```js
var vec = function(x,y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
};
var ray = function(start,end){
    this.origin = start;
    this.direction = end;
};
  
var center_x =0, center_y=0;
(function() {
   var rayInstance = new ray(new vec(center_x, center_y), new vec(2, 10));
   alert(rayInstance.direction.x + " " + rayInstance.direction.y);
})();
```